# Открытие Яндекс.Карт

Tags: android, java, yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся  проблемой отображения Яндекс карт. Вроде и пример официальный есть и руки от куда надо, но не запускается собственное приложение.

метод открытия активити с картой

```
public final String MAPKIT = "yandex.intent.category.MAPKIT";
    public  void open(View v)
    {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(MAPKIT);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this,maps_page.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

активити с картиой

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:apiKey="api key" />
</LinearLayout>
```

и сам запуск активити с картой

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceData)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceData);
        setContentView(R.layout.maps);

    }
```

Но активити не запускается, уже все перепробовал. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо запускать не так. Сначала выясните пакет стороннего приложения (в вашем случае это наверное нечто вроде **ru.yandex.map.blah.blah**), затем напишите кодик типа такого:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("ru.yandex.map.blah.blah"); 
startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

Суть в том, что вы заранее не можете знать главный активити, а приведенный кусочек позволяет найти лончер внешнего приложения.

Comment: проблема то в том, что активити с картой находится в моем пакете, весь приведенный код лежит в одном пакете.

Comment: API key на карту получил и задекларировал его? Разрешения на доступ к GPS прописал в манифесте?

Comment: я не думаю, чтобы будет краш активити из-за этого, но да, это все сделано. активити даже не запускается, он пытается его открыть, но происходит экстренное завершение